# Wireless receiver and Ethernet switch?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, lan, streaming, switch

Is there a device that can pick the router wireless signal and allow LAN connection between two computers by itself?

I want to use Steam In-Home streaming without having a large Ethernet cable throughout my home just to connect two computers together in my bedroom.

The Router is D-Link ADSL2/2 and the WiFi speed is abysmal for streaming, if the "receiver" allows LAN traffic between both devices it will work perfectly.

To simplify the concept take a look at the following sketch.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

been ages, but i believe you are looking for a device called a wireless bridge.

many routers on the market have an option to act as one.

you can also call the router manufacturer and check with them about the model you buy, or check the manual.

an issue is it may need to be the same model router.. and a router-modem without bridge mode might not have able to see the other router.   When you look at routers with more features it is quite common for them to not include modems.

Comment: What is really important is that Steam In-Home Streaming can recognize the ethernet connection between these two computers at the same time be connected to the internet via wireless.

Do you have recommendations for D-Link ADSL2/2?

Comment: @Gabriel since you mention ADSL maybe you're in the UK or Australia.. as the UK and maybe Australia use ADSL as opposed to just plain DSL. For the UK one is in luck, for an ISP called Zen can give very good advice on reliable routers.  Some in the UK have found that so-called top makes like netgear can be a bit unreliable... dlink is i think meant to be not as good as netgear in reliability last time I checked.  draytek vigor are  apparently very reliable and I have a very reliable adsl modem (thomson!) speedtouch recommended by my isp zen but it's not wireless.

Comment: @Gabriel for all the devices, router and both wired comps to be recognized is no problem. that would happen. you can call dlink to check it would.. Just make sure all the devices are on the same subnet. e.g. 192.168.x.y or 10.x.y.z and don't mix subnets or they won't recognize each other